# Octahedral mapping seam issue

Tags: graphics, 3d

ddgi: https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/RTXGI
Each probe is stored using an octahedral parameterization of a sphere unwrapped to the unit square, but have seam issue,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMBBy.jpg)
I don't know why I'm getting this error, how to fix it? help me.